# UWP SplitView DisplayMode Overlay - not in focus

Tags: xaml, data-binding, uwp, uwp-xaml, splitview

I have a `SplitView`:

```
<SplitView Name="splitView" 
   DisplayMode="{Binding SplitViewDisplayMode}" 
   IsPaneOpen="{Binding SplitViewIsPaneOpen}" 
   OpenPaneLength="200" CompactPaneLength="51"/>
```

I am also using `VisualStateManager` to adjust the `SplitView` based on application window size: (example)

```
<VisualState.StateTriggers>
   <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="500"></AdaptiveTrigger>
</VisualState.StateTriggers>
```

Thus far everything works correctly, but I ran into an unexpected result when the trigger above and state below are activated.

```
<VisualState.Setters>
   <Setter Value="True" Target="splitView.IsPaneOpen"></Setter>
   <Setter Value="Overlay" Target="splitView.DisplayMode"></Setter>
</VisualState.Setters>
```

I cant seem to find a way to detect the event so that my `ViewModel` knows when the `SplitView` pane focus is lost. Right now as designed Overlay displays until the user clicks the view (as designed), but I'd like to know, when the `SplitView` Overlay is collapsed so that I can add additional binding events into my `HamburgerMenu`.

From what I am experiencing it appears that `VisualStateManager` doesn't update/change my bindings

```
DisplayMode="{Binding SplitViewDisplayMode}"
```

Any ideas as to how I can discover if/when the Overlay disappears/Closes?

The only thing I can think of is to create methods that discover the Window size, and then determine if the SplitView should be `Inline`/`Compact`/`Overlay`..  This is doable but would result in a lot of potential combinations.

Any thoughts or ideas on how to detect or get `SplitView` to tell me if `Overlay` is `Collapsed` when a user clicks a control outside of the `SplitView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the bindings work, you have to specify them as **two way** bindings. Without this, they will only update the UI with your changes in code, not the other way around:

```
<SplitView Name="splitView" 
       DisplayMode="{Binding SplitViewDisplayMode, Mode=TwoWay}" 
       IsPaneOpen="{Binding SplitViewIsPaneOpen, Mode=TwoWay}" 
       OpenPaneLength="200" CompactPaneLength="51"/>
```

Now your properties should be properly updated whenever the state changes.

Comment: Don't know why i missed that one...  Thank you!  I also noticed that
    DisplayMode="{Binding SplitViewDisplayMode, Mode=TwoWay}"

Worked only as a object and not a string:
    private object _SplitViewDisplayMode;
        public object SplitViewDisplayMode
        {
            get => _SplitViewDisplayMode;
            set => SetProperty(ref _SplitViewDisplayMode, value);
        }

Thanks again